# How to refresh a TableView in window A from a Window B in javaFX? (Edit)

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a window A (main Window) it contains a TableView and a button, when the button is clicked it opens a new window (inscription window) that contains two TextFields (in order to set first name and last name) and a "save" button. What I want to happen is when I click the "save" button in the **inscription window**, my TableView in the **main window** gets refreshed and shows both first name and last name in a new row.

Here is my main window controller:

```
public class FxmlMainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<DataArray> dataTable;
    
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DataArray, String> firstNameCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DataArray, String> lastNameCol;
    
    public static ObservableList<DataArray> DATA_LIST;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

       DATA_LIST = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new DataArray("Michael", "Jackson")); 
       firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DataArray, String>("firstName"));
       lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DataArray, String>("lastName"));
       dataTable.getItems().addAll(DATA_LIST);
    }    

    //Open the inscription window
    @FXML
    private void openInscriptionWindow(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/inscriptionui/FxmlInscription.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
}
```

Here is my inscription window:

```
public class FxmlInscriptionController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField firsNametInput;   //first name TextField

    @FXML
    private TextField lastNameInput;   //last name TextField

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

    //Show the inserted first name and last name in my TableView in the main window
    @FXML
    private void saveData(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {
   
    FxmlMainController.DATA_LIST = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new DataArray(firsNametInput.getText(), lastNameInput.getText()));

        /*
        what should I write more here to make my TableView
        get refreshed automatically and show the new inserted values?
         */
    }

}
```

And here is my DataArray class:

```
public class DataArray {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public DataArray(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

I would appreciate your help
Thank you

Comment: Structure/strategy here just seems wrong to me. You should pass the items list from the table to the second controller. Then in the second controller: 1. get the data from the UI,  2. perform the database insert, 3. add the new item to the list.  Then the table will automatically update. There is no need to pull the whole list back from the database.

Comment: Anyway, the reason it's not working as you have it, is that you're loading `mainUI.fxml` a second time. That creates a new table, and the controller you get is the controller for the UI containing that new table. That's never displayed, so you never see the changes to it. You want to update the existing table, not create a new one.

Comment: @James_D thank you, I understand the logic, I tried it but the table doesn't refresh automatically, I tried a button in my mainUI that calls the refresh method on my TableView instance when clicked (right after I did your logic) and it worked well, but refreshing it from the button in the second UI doesnt work unfortunately.

Comment: that's still neither minimal (simply removing the imports won't do - please read the referenced help page to understand how to focus code onto exactly __one__ problem) nor does is follow naming conventions ..

Comment: @kleopatra I will take that into consideration next time, thank you

Comment: edit your question to comply to the rules .. the sooner the better are your chances to get it answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the table's item list to the second controller:

```
@FXML
private void openInscriptionWindow(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/inscriptionui/FxmlInscription.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();

    FxmlInscriptionController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setTableItems(dataTable.getItems());

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

and then simply add the new item to the list:

```
public class FxmlInscriptionController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField firsNametInput;   //first name TextField

    @FXML
    private TextField lastNameInput;   //last name TextField

    private ObservableList<DataArray> tableItems ;

    public void setTableItems(ObservableList<DataArray> tableItems) {
        this.tableItems = tableItems ;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

    //Show the inserted first name and last name in my TableView in the main window
    @FXML
    private void saveData(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {
   
        tableItems.add(new DataArray(firsNametInput.getText(), lastNameInput.getText()));

    }

}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer! I'm sorry for my late reply. BTW I also had to pass a reference of my tableview to get it refreshed from the other scene. there is just one Question: When you load the fxml file in this way it works:
`FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/inscriptionui/FxmlInscription.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
FxmlInscriptionController controller = loader.getController();`
However, if you pass the fxml file URL as an inputstream this way: 
`Parent root = loader.load("/inscriptionui/FxmlInscription.fxml");` 
it doens't work, why?

Comment: @Madjid You should not have to pass the `TableView` itself to the controller; if you need that you are doing something which breaks the connection between the table view and its items list (e.g. calling `setItems(...)` after passing the list).

Comment: @Madjid The `FXMLLoader.load(URL)` method is a static method (read the docs; and surely your IDE gives you a warning if you call this method from a reference). Thus using that method cannot change the state of the `FXMLLoader` instance `loader`, and in particular its controller remains null.